# How to extract value from an object made by deriv()?

Tags: r

Consider the derivative of the cumulative distribution  function `pnorm()` of Gaussian, it is the probability density of Gaussian `dnorm()`.
It is done by the following;

```
#  Calculate derivative function and store to object a
   a <- deriv((y ~  pnorm(x,0,1)   ), c("x"), func = TRUE)

# Check the value of  at 4
    > a(4)
    [1] 0.9999683
    attr(,"gradient")
                    x
    [1,] 0.0001338302
    > dnorm(4)
    [1] 0.0001338302
```

I want to extract the value `0.0001338302` from the object `a(4)`.

The word "extract" means, e.g., as following manner, but it is not desired one, because it extract the first value `0.9999683`.

```
a(4)[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the attribute `"gradient"`

```
attr(a(4), "gradient")[1]
#[1] 0.0001338302
```

`"gradient"` attribute of `a(4)` returns a matrix of which we extract the first element.

Comment: Long time no see!! I have to learn about `attr`. Thank you for teaching me many times!